# Refresh my content immediately after updating the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am sending information over to an external server which updates some content on the database at that server. The update is working but the updated information is not shown on my application. I need to close the application and re-open to view the updated content. Is there anyway I can make the refresh occur without having to restart application.

I was trying to make the refresh occur after a successful POST but it doesn't happen. The POST occurs from a page with the ID of #update. I want to just refresh the content of that page with the new information from the database. The application is built using JQuery Mobile.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myURL",
        data: {},
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Server down. Try Later")
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //I am able to arrive here after a successful update to the server. 
            $.mobile.changePage("#update"); //Doesn't refresh
            alert("Update Successful");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does your "Update Successful" alert work?

Comment: on changepage set allowSamePageTransition to true. You may still need to get the new info on pageshow...

Comment: @Zlatev Yes it works.

Comment: @ezanker Do you mean I run onpage event and rerun the entire ajax call again to get information? Can I get an example.

Comment: If you always run your ajax call that populates the page on the pageshow or beforeshow event, you should be good.